# Looking for Uniswap-like Swap Routers on Ethereum Mainnet

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, uniswap

Could someone kindly provide me with a list of Ethereum mainnet swap routers that are derived from the Uniswap V2 router? Similar to how SushiSwap is a fork of the Uniswap router.

I couldn't find any other examples besides SushiSwap on the Ethereum mainnet. Most of the examples I found were related to different blockchain networks.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking for lists of external web resources are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone kindly provide me with a list of Ethereum mainnet swap routers that are derived from the Uniswap V2 router?

There is no such list, because these smart contracts are not registered any way or anywhere.